# VMware/VirtualBox and partitioning

Tags: partitioning, virtual-machine

I am completely new to the concept of virtual machines and am trying to set up my first VirtualBox VM. Specifically I am trying to run Ubuntu as the guest on my Windows 7 host machine.

I'm at a stage where it's telling me that I have to partition my virtual disk in order to correctly install Ubuntu. I know this may be a stupid question, but I have so much treasured data on my hard drive, I'd hate to somehow lose it while partitioning my VM's disk!

**If I move forward with this partitioning, does it just partition the free space I allocated to it when I configured the VM in the VirtualBox wizard, or do I run any risk (at all) of overwriting something on my Windows machine?**

Comment: There's no risk. However, I do daily backups.

Comment: Thanks @RGB - I figured as much but had to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual disk will **not** overwrite your hard drive's data. The partitioning just occurs within the virtual disk you created, not your real hard drive.

It's called "virtual" because it's simply a VDI file that is either fixed size (file size is what you set it to be) or dynamically expanding (starts small, file size increases as you write more data).