# Installing Kali Linux on VirtualBox and the data on the host computer

Tags: kali-linux

If I install Kali Linux on my VirtualBox which is in my usb, will it hurt the data on my host computer?
It says it "partitions (?)" my hardware. Does it mean the virtual hardware or the actual hardware of the host computer?

Comment: Maybe this question  [VMware/VirtualBox and partitioning](https://superuser.com/q/340079/172747) can answer yours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VMware/VirtualBox and partitioning](https://superuser.com/questions/340079/vmware-virtualbox-and-partitioning)

Answer (score 0):

Kali linux will be installed in your virtual driver. The virtual disk will be partitioned, as any other virtual machine, and your host system will not be affected by this installation.

Answer (score 0):

It means Kali will partition your VirtualBox hard drive, not your host's hardware. Everything you do in a VirtualBox machine stays in the VirtualBox machine.

Everytime you create a VirtualBox machine, it creates a VMDK file which is your virtual hard drive, not your actual host drive. It has one partition. Probably Kali will partition it to you.